# Python CGI: Translate from stdout to html (e.g. replace \n with <BR>)

Tags: python, cgi

I have a great command line program that prints to stdout. I want to let people run this through CGI. In the CGI version, I want to have the same output (with `"<BR>"` instead of `"\n"`).

My `cgi_main` works by calling `my real_main`; there are a lot of options to process and it was bad design to do that multiple times. But since `real_main` calls `print`, I don't know how to change `"\n"` to `"<BR>"` post hoc.

I could easily change all instances of `print` to go to a `tempfile` and then dump that at the end, but it seems inelegant to change the existing command line version so much.

One option is to have `real_main` call another function (passing along argv); that new function returns values. Then real_main prints those values. cgi_main would call the same function, but print the values differently.

Another option is to use a class member/static function everywhere I use print now. This class could be told whether to reformat or not. Then switching between command line and CGI output would just require changing the `reform` argument.

Here is an example of how I thought this class and function could work:
    class cgi_tools:
        def **init**(self, reform = False):
            self.reform = reform
        def myprint(self, *args):
            if not self.reform:
                print(args)
            for i,x in enumerate(args):
                if type(x) == str:
                    self.myprint(x.replace('\n', '
')),
                elif type(x) in atoms: # check if x is an atom (i.e. int, float, etc.):
                    print x,
                else:
                    self.myprint(x),
                if i != len(args)-1:
                    print ' ',
            print ''

With this I ran into trouble trying to think of all atoms (i.e. irreducible objects) in Python. I couldn't find a built-in function for this test, and I thought writing it myself was a brittle idea.

I tried to use `insepct` to print the source code of `print`, but I couldn't do that!
print sys.out.print:

```
import inspect
print inspect.getsource(print) # this does not work!
```

All of this seems like a classic Python CGI question, but I couldn't find a great solution. I know how to patch things together in a sloppy way and get what I want, but I would love your advice on how to be elegant. I want to grow, and I don't want to program sloppily anymore.

Thanks a lot for your thoughts and advice.<br>
-Oliver

Comment: Print's source is in C, not python, that's why inspect doesn't return the source.

Comment: why not just send a text/plain MIME header instead of text/html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the start of your CGI script, put `print "Content-type: text/plain\r\n\r\n"`. The result will show up on a webpage the same as on a console.

In general, if I want to have two variations on a program, one that formats output in HTML and the other that outputs plain text, I abstract as much of the logic as I can into routines or objects that do no output, then have separate output routines for the variations. See for example http://jcomeau.unternet.net/src/colorforth/as/cf2text, which is symlinked to cf2html and cf2ansi; the same program produces 3 different outputs depending on which symlink is called. Note that this is old code and I don't program the same way any more, but maybe you'll get some useful ideas from it; maybe not.

Actually, looking over the link I gave you, I used a different strategy there, using a global to indicate the desired output style. I don't have any recent open-source code with a better example to give you, it's all owned by my clients.

Here's one way to modify your output without changing your print statements:

```
>>> import sys, StringIO
>>> oldout = sys.stdout
>>> sys.stdout = newout = StringIO.StringIO()
>>> for line in 'this', 'that', 'the other': print line
... 
>>> sys.stdout = oldout
>>> print newout.getvalue().replace('\n', '<br />\n')
this<br />
that<br />
the other<br />
```

If you use this method, then you can change your content-type to text/html and use any other HTML functionality. For more complex modifications of the output you can use regular expression substitution. And if you want the output as lines, you can:

```
>>> newout.seek(0)
>>> newout.readlines()
['this\n', 'that\n', 'the other\n']
```

Comment: +1 Thanks @jcomeau_ictx and apologies for the simple question. In general, if I wanted to do other replacements (like lists show up as tables in html, etc.), what would be the ideal way to do it?

Comment: Cheers. Is there a way to also let me put <img ...> tags in and have them load?

Comment: Having CGI hijack sys.stdout is a pretty great idea.